# Angular 2+ : Component style keeps affecting other components

Tags: angular

Got home component with `background-color:red` written into its scss and then got user component with `background-color:green` written into its scss. I start my app, I am at home, got red background, go to user page, got green background. Works like it should...but now when I go back my home component background is still green. All components have `ViewEncapsulation.None`.
If I start navigation from user page, same things happen, but background colors vica-vera.

I always understood that point of component style is to affect only its component and not others. Is it not how that supposed to work?

Edit: If I set `ViewEncapsulation.Emulated` I see no styling from component style scss file being applied, so both pages are having white background.
This is how my home component file looks:

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';


@Component({
    selector: 'app-home',
    templateUrl: './home.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./home.component.scss'],
    encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.Emulated,
})

export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

    ngOnInit() {

    }

}
```

Edit: You see my problem was that I was setting background color for `<body>`, but the body aint part of the template, this why `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.Emulated` and component stylesheets aint affecting it.

Comment: `ViewEncapsulation.None` literally means "don't isolate view css"

Comment: could you reproduce your issue on stackblitz/ plnkr?

Comment: @TusharWalzade I think I figured it out. Thing is I am setting background color for body tag and body tag aint part of home or user template, so the component style is not applying for body.

Comment: Could you show us a scss file ?

Comment: You use bad design, you get bad results. There is a lot of ways to style the `body` without even bothering about view encapsulation. If your style collide, encapsulate. if your style aren't getting applied, check the variable names. Finally, if you don't know how to style the body using Angular, please provide a [mcve] so that we can show you how to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to encapsulate your view to **`Emulated`**, so that your component decorator will look like the following -

```
@Component({
    // ...
    encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.Emulated,
})
```

*It will scope your styles to the specific component only.*

**[Here](https://angular.io/guide/view-encapsulation)**'s more reference about View Encapsulation

Comment: `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.Emulated` is same as having it not written that at all. So what happens now is that both home and user page will have white backgrounds.

Answer (score 0):

The reason it never changes back to the expected color.

Because the first component loads its css in to the dom and stays their forever until the window is not closed. And the reason why the second time of route change is correct because it will override your same class, ids or tag styles that are existing once the second 
 component is rendered.

So my suggestion is, make the use of router events and detect each paths you want to change colors and change the body element class.

example:

```
export class AppComponent {
  name = 'Angular';

  constructor(private router: Router) {
    this.router.events.subscribe((event) => {
      if (event instanceof NavigationEnd) {
        console.log(event.url)
        if (event.url == '/') {
          document.body.className = 'home';
        } else if (event.url == '/test') {
          document.body.className = 'test';
        } else if (event.url == '/hello') {
          document.body.className = 'hello';
        }
      }
    });
  }
}
```

see stackblitz below for the complete guide:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-svktf1