# Why does changing css for a single component affect all other components?

Tags: css, angular

**Goal**: Have CSS only affect the component its on, not others. I only wanted to affect my dropdown, not other text entry fields:

[image]

**Background/Problem**: I understand why it would affect multiple items on the same page (mat-form-field's). But don't understand why it would affect OTHER pages. I looked into it but still unsure.

**What I tried**:
For example, I originally had:

```
::ng-deep .mat-form-field-appearance-outline .mat-form-field-flex {
    height: 40px !important
}

::ng-deep .mat-form-field-infix {
    padding-top: 1px !important;
    padding-bottom: 2px !important;
}
```

But it was affecting the spacing of all form-fields on the page, **so I edited it to be**:

```
::ng-deep .mat-form-field-appearance-outline .mat-form-field-flex {
    height: 40px !important
}

::ng-deep .mat-form-field-appearance-outline .mat-form-field-infix {
    padding-top: 1px !important;
    padding-bottom: 2px !important;
}
```

Other unchanged CSS:

```
.title-container {
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 8px;
}

.language-field {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    margin-top: -16px;
    width: 115px;
    height: 20px !important;
}
```

This fixed that, but it is still odd to me that changing something on login.component.css would affect all other pages in the site such as profile.component.css

Here is associated HTML for login.component:

```
<div class="title-container">
    <mat-card-title class="text-center">
        Please Sign In
    </mat-card-title>

    <form [formGroup]="_siteForm">
        <mat-form-field class="language-field" appearance="outline">
            <mat-select (selectionChange)="changeSite($event)" [value]="languages[i].value">
                <mat-option *ngFor="let language of languages" [value]="language.value">
                    {{language.viewValue}}
                </mat-option>
            </mat-select>
        </mat-form-field>
    </form>        
</div>
```

**When I researched into this**:
I found some SO articles (such as [Angular 2+ : Component style keeps affecting other components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54020841/angular-2-component-style-keeps-affecting-other-components)) mentioning using encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation
However, when looking through the site, I don't see this used anywhere, however there is css on different components that all mention mat-form-field but with different values. This seems like it would indicate that encapsulation is not needed.
In regular HTML I did not use to have these problems, but am confused on how this is working in Angular. Does this have something to do with Angular being a SPA?

Comment: Note that `::ng-deep` is [deprecated](https://angular.io/guide/deprecations), but with no timeline as to when it will be removed.

Answer (score 3):

I think it's your `::ng-deep`, remove that.

Then use a specific class name and declare it in that components css file.
e.g. in **home.component.css**

```
.mat-form-field-flex {
    height: 40px !important
}
```

Comment: Thanks Lilly_Code. It sounds like you are saying: .myclass {
    padding-top: 1px !important;
    padding-bottom: 2px !important;
}

But would html still remain
<mat-form-field class="language-field" appearance="outline">
or
<mat-form-field class="myclass" appearance="outline">

Comment: I tried adding these to the "language-field" class from the html but it did not work. I Also tried removing the ngdeep but then it removed the styles (box was in a weird place, weird size)

Answer (score 3):

It's slightly hard to grasp what you're trying to show here without a code snippet with that CSS.

But if it's breaking Angular's view encapsulation which all components have by default, I'd be almost positive it's because you're using `!important` selectors, these should really only be used in the rarest of situations -  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity

The reason for this is because using `!important` will break the css specificity Angular uses to `encapsulate` it's components.

Css specificity works like so.

Inline styles are worth 1000pts

Id's are worth 100pts

Classes are worth 10pts

Elements are worth 1pt

The `!important` is essentially worth infinite points it always takes precedence.

`div>p>.className` = 12pts
`div>p>#classname` = 102pts

This means that any styles in

`div>p>#classname`

will take priority over any styles in

`div>p>.classname`

I won't go into details here about how Angular achieves there encapsulation with this technique, if your interested here's a good article - https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2015/06/29/shadow-dom-strategies-in-angular2.html

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you haven't set encapsulation to ViewEncapsulation.None

```
@Component({
  selector: "my-component",
  templateUrl: "./my-component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./my-component.scss"],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I also got the same problem. You are using ::ng-deep. ::ng-deep is a global level element it affect all the component. So, use :host as prefix. :host will contain the ::ng-deep in the same component. It won't allow it to affect other components. Use this :host ::ng-deep. Replace all ::ng-deep with :host ::ng-deep.